# Saving to SQLDb, more reliable in onPause() or onStop()?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm a little confused in trying to save values to an SQLiteDatabase. I want my app to seamlessly save the state and data, so I first put the "save to SQLDb (AsyncTask)" code into onStop(), and the "load from SQLDb" code in onStart(). However, I've noticed this is unreliable: pressing the back or home button calls onPause(), and *sometimes* onStop(), and when the app is brought back to the foreground, the Spinner items are sometimes there, sometimes empty, and the rest of the Views/content is also unpredictable due to whether onStop()/onStart() had been called.

So I moved the "save" code to onPause(), and the "load" code to onResume(). Now, I've read in the docs that this kind of stuff shouldn't be done in these methods, but for the most part, it works better than onStop() and onStart(). However, still, it is not exactly reliable: sometimes the AsyncTask never seems to end. If the user brings the app back to the foreground before the AsyncTask finishes, it leads to the above-mentioned unpredictable Views.

Where should I be saving this stuff?

Note: I have two Spinners that the user can dynamically add items to, as well as a GridView that must repopulate itself based on one of the Spinners (one gridChild per Spinner item). This kind of stuff, to my knowledge, cannot be saved easily by SharedPreferences or similar state-saving techniques, it must be done by database (especially since there are an indefinite amount of objects being saved, depending on what the user input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you persist your data `onPause()` and restore it `onResume()`.

This is because `onStop()` is not guaranteed to be called if the system needs to kill your app.

Comment: Right, so how do I solve the issue of when the AsyncTask takes an unusually long time to close the database? If the user hits the home button, but then brings the app back to the foreground immediately, the app breaks (the Spinners and GridView don't load properly).

Comment: How about disabling the controls until the AsyncTask is finished?

Comment: I marked this as correct since it did answer one of the questions I asked, though I'm still having trouble. It might be that I'm not closing the database somewhere because it stalls (doesn't finish the task) when it goes to onPause().

Comment: If you are using an SQLiteOpenHelper, there is no reason to close the database. However, you have to close all cursors.

Comment: Whoa, yes. The tutorial I followed doesn't close the cursor for each getter in the DatabaseHelper class. That may be the problem.

Comment: Dan, I haven't solved that problem despite closing the cursors, so I made a new question for it. If you have a few moments please take a look. Much appreciated!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859063/android-sqlitedb-doesnt-finish-adding-values